# How to forward fill NaN values in pandas data frame?

Tags: pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
        S.No.           Name                  DOB Gender  Profile/work Order-History  
    0     1.0      Sam Smith  1989-01-05 00:00:00   Male         abc     A
    1     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     B
    2     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     C   
    3     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     D   
    4     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     E   
    5     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     F  
    6     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     G   
    7     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     H   
    8     NaN            NaN                  NaN    NaN         NaN     I
```

How may I forward fill the NaN values to achieve the desired output as below?

```
    S.No.           Name                  DOB Gender  Profile/work  Order-History
0     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         A   
1     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         B
2     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         C
3     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         D
4     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         E
5     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         F
6     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         G
7     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         H
8     1.0      Sam Smith  1983-12-29 00:00:00   Male  abc         I
```

Comment: Pandas has a method argument in .fillna(). Just specify 'ffill'.  ```import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()   
df.reset_index(inplace=True)   
df.fillna(method='ffill')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working forward filling missing values, if all data are in second row (in first row is header):

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx').ffill()
```